# Why does "git add *" excludes .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I've got .gitignore file with names of excluded files. When I delete .git folder and do `git init`, after `git add *` I would expect all files to be added that are not ignored by .gitignore. However, .gitignore shows as untracked file in `git status` and I have to manually add it with `git add .gitignore` even if I include `!.gitignore` in .gitignore.

Comment: It seems that your shell ignores dotfiles in glob expansion. It's impossible to say more without knowing which shell you use and how you have configured it. At any rate, this is a simple "how do I use my operating system" question and has nothing to do with programming. Personally, I always use `git add .` and side-step the whole glob business.

Comment: Read this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70928/shell-wildcards-and-dot-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `*` in your command is actually replaced with names of files (and directories) from your current directory **except** ones staring w `.`. If you want to include also *.gitignore* you should call:

```
git add * .gitignore
```

If you want include all dot files call:

```
git add * .[!.]*
```

If you are using *zsh*, you can use simpler pattern:

```
 git add * .*
```

Comment: Err, be careful with `.*`: it includes `..` and `git add ..` includes much more than the OP expects!

Comment: @MatthieuMoy "Careful" - definitely correct. But in the OP's case (when CWD is the root directory of the repo), git will not include anything outside. A different case would be when you're in a subdirectory.

Comment: I get `fatal: ..: '..' is outside repository`, but it answers my question. I wanted to git add * to include all files needed for the repo, but I guess I'll just `git add * .gitignore`